# Apply filter for date failing in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm getting date from a rest service as

```
$scope.dob="1989-10-17 00:00:00"
```

How can I convert /apply filter to this date to look like normal date (without time).

I tried with splicing the time part but this is inside ng-repeat.It's not working

Comment: Have you tried `{{ dob | date:'short' }}` in the template? See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Yes @Dimitry.Not working

Comment: {{ dob | date:'shortDate' }} this should just get the date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note the format [`date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) understands:

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.

"1989-10-17 00:00:00" can't be parsed. Instead it should be: "1989-10-17T00:00:00Z"

Comment: You're welcome. Also consider using timestamps instead of string.